# Get vim to modify the file instead of moving the new version on it?

Tags: vim

I want my app to update automatically when I save my files. So I use inotify (ubuntu) to create watchers that detect the events.

The issue is vim **overwrites** the file instead of updating it. So my watcher is lost after the first update.

I wonder, is there a way to setup vim so it doesn't use swap files and updates directly the file ?

(I tried `:set noswapfile` and the `-n` option, that removes the swap file without changing the behaviour)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this:

```
:set backupcopy=yes
```

Comment: Thank you now I have the modify event triggered.

Comment: this doesn't work for me on OSX 10.11.2 (El Capitan), I still get two change events on `grunt-contrib-watch` when saving a file

Answer (score 2):

With Vim, you can control this via the `'backupcopy'` setting; however, I once took an alternative route and monitored the directories, not the files themselves:

```
inotifywait --quiet --monitor --event modify --format '%w%f' "$dir"
```

This required some more processing in my script (checking whether the modified file matches my list), but also enabled me to capture newly created files, too.