# inotify IN_CLOSE_WRITE fires only once for manually edited file

Tags: python, logging, vim, inotify

I'm running python with gevent and gevent_inotifyx to watch a file for any modification using `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` mask to wait for the file to be closed after write. I get my event fired first time but not after that. I use vim to manually edit the file.

Used a different log file to watch, and that works as expected. This is a python logging file and any time log file is changed with content I get an event fired.

Has anyone come across this situation before? Could this be due to some sync'ing or flushing to disk?

Comment: What specific commands issued within vim do you expect to see accompanied by an `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event?

Comment: install the command line tool `inotifywait`, run it and check the events it reports when you're editing the file through vim. If it reports the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event (like it did when i attempted this at my end), the probably is likely in your code

Comment: In vim I use `:wq` to save it, I'll try `inotifywait` to debug and let you know, thanks.

Comment: I tried this command, `inotifywait -m -e close_write /home/python_tools/logging.conf` Are you using these switches as well with inotifywait? I don't see any events at all when I manually edit it with vim. But when I use same command for a log file I get the close_write event raised when the file has been modified. I'm starting to think if vim does a syscall which doesn't sync. I'll try it with other editors as well..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get vim to modify the file instead of moving the new version on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507344/get-vim-to-modify-the-file-instead-of-moving-the-new-version-on-it)

Comment: The answer below works, but I still don't understand how it works the first time and then it doesn't though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Vim writes the file contents to a temporary file and then moves that over the original, see `:help backup`. Since this is now a different file (handle), your events stop firing.

You can make Vim override the original file by setting

```
:set backupcopy=yes
```

If you want to handle this generally, you'd have to monitor the file's directory instead and watch for file moves, too.