# Vim is triggering multiple saves

Tags: vim, save

I have been encountering a problem using `nodemon` together with `vim`

nodemon is a deamon that watches files and starts a script every time the file changes.

Strangely, when I run nodemon and save a file with vim, nodemon detects two filechanges of the file.

You can replicate this issue with the following snippet:

```
npm install nodemon -g
echo "console.log('hello world');" > server.js
nodemon server.js -V
vim server.js
```

Than try to save the file (with `:w`)

It seems that everytime I save a file from vim, the watch gets triggered twice.
However, if you open `server.js` with `pico`, the file changes only once.

I don't think the problem lies with nodemon, so I'm asking here what could create this particular behaviour ?

I have also tried to disable all vim plubin `vim -u NONE server.js` but this didn't help.

They also is a corresponding issue on github: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/349, however, it doesn't seem easy to know what is happening.

Comment: You may want to take a look at: [Analysis of inotify events for different editors](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Analysis-of-inotify-events-for-different-editors).

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the file write handling of Vim. See `:help 'backupcopy'` for an explanation. Editors like Vim replace the original file with a temporary backup to avoid losing the file contents completely. This is also an issue when watching the file for changes via `inotifywait` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507344/get-vim-to-modify-the-file-instead-of-moving-the-new-version-on-it)). A workaround for that is to

```
:set backupcopy=yes
```

You'll still see events for the backup file, but at least it's for another file. To completely forego the safety of a backup, you can addditionally

```
:set nobackup
```

Comment: I've executed :set nobackup but I still get "two saves"

Comment: Probably need to set "nowritebackup" as well.